# How to wrap a text using iText in java?

Tags: java, itext

I am having Existing PDF Template Document, In that i am having Text fields, Text area etc.. In that fields i want to write a dynamic content, which i am getting from database.

As of now i am writing dynamic content using x,y co-ordinates of fields with help of pdfStamper. The Problem is **length of content is exceeding the text field witdth and overlapping on other text** Please refer below image.

[image]

I want wrap this text when reaches maximum length of text field.

Code i was used for writing content is.

```
    //Read Template
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("src\\main\\resources\\templates\\IES.pdf");
  //Create copy of template
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader,
                    new FileOutputStream("D:\\pdfSamples\\Output\\IES.pdf"));
//Initialize additional content object
                PdfContentByte content=initialReExamScreenOnePrintPDF.createNewContentByte(pageNo, pdfStamper);

                //Start Placing Text-Radio-CheckBox
                content.beginText();

content.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, "Some Text",36, 123,0);
//End Content
content.endText();
pdfStamper.close();
pdfReader.close();
```

Please Help on this to fix this issue

Comment: You talk about "fields", but you aren't using the PDF as a form. Furthermore, you are using `beginText()`/`endText()` and you're not even setting a font in your code. Why aren't you using `ColumnText`? Where are you getting the coordinates from? Did you read [How to fit a String inside a rectangle?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-fit-string-inside-rectangle), [How to add text inside a rectangle?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-text-inside-rectangle),  and other similar FAQ items in the documentation? (Why didn't you read the official documentation?)

Comment: Yes i didn't used PDF as Form. Actually here i am referring field is space for write a dynamic content. And i am setting **font** inside **createNewContentByte()** Method. Using some other tool to get coordinates of place to write.  I read about rectangle, But my Need is any way to do auto wrapping based on content length?, If using rectangle, i need extend the size of rectangle manually if content length is increased. So i am searching for any other solution for auto wrap. Please help me.

Comment: I can not help you if you don't understand that an `x`, `y` and a `length` is not sufficient to wrap text. You need an `x`, `y`, `length` (or `width`) and `height`. Or, to put it simply: you need a `Rectangle`. As long as you refuse to investigate my suggestion to use a `Rectangle`, you cannot be helped.

Comment: I am not refusing to use `Rectangle`, i understood the rectangle class features and uses. We can get status of **content is fixed with defined width of rectangle or not** by using `columnText.go()` method. Based on this status we have to alter the width and height of `Rectangle`.

Comment: Without using `Rectangle`, Is any other properties is available for to do auto wrap the text? Or only the solution is need to use `Rectangle` for wrap the text?.

Comment: Define auto-wrap. You make it sound as a common concept, but it isn't. You can use low-level PDF syntax functionality in iText to position every single character at whatever position you want. It's a matter of doing the math based on the *advance* of every character (as defined in the font). The question is: are you a PDF specialist? If not, why wouldn't use a more convenient way and ask iText to wrap the text inside a rectangle?